# Create a custom dataset for pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I have images and labels both in tensor format, where the shape of the images is torch.Size([6656, 300, 300, 3]) and the labels with shape of torch.Size([6656]), and I wish to create a class dataset in order to link both images and labels together for image classification in pytorch, is that possible?

Comment: Please show your code. Resizing should not rotate.

Comment: Hi Cris, I have updated the code

Comment: The code you posted is welcome, but you should show us also the `import`  statements that you have used. In particular, what is `image` in `image.imread` and what is `resize`  in `resize(imagei, ...)` - tia.

Comment: Hi gboffi, is it clearer now?

Comment: I don’t see anything that would rotate the image. This is what I would do: get rid of the loop, load just one image. Then show the image to one axes without resizing it, and to another after resizing it. Then compare those two. It might just be the change of aspect ratio that you see, not an actual rotation.

Comment: Hi Lim, thank you for the edit. My GUESS, `matplotlib.image` and `skimage` have different ideas  about the orientation of an image. My suggestion, read an image using a method from `skimage`, resize it, save it using, again, a method from `skimage`, and finally check the orientation of the saved image using an external utility.

Comment: Thanks all! I have found the solution, when I'm using skimage to import the image, everything worked just fine

Comment: Check the docs on pytorch [datasets](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-dataset-for-your-files). It seems to be what you're asking for...